# Apply filmic color management to an EXR file - post processing in photoshop

Tags: color-management, .exr

I am taking EXR files to photoshop for post processing, but I want the filmic color management applied. Is there a different file format I should be using, or is there a way to apply filmic color management to an EXR file?

Answer (score 7):

Photoshop and other software of its ilk are display referred imaging applications. While PS will load an EXR, it does not possess the quality of controls one requires to properly manipulate scene referred photographic imagery.

To deal with a strictly display referred application and suffer as little quality loss as possible, save to a display referred format such as a 16 bit TIFF using the Filmic Base Log Encoding. It would then be possible to sculpt your own 'S' shaped curve to adjust contrast, or convert the Filmic set to the limited LUT format that Photoshop can understand.

DaVinci's Resolve has the granularity and more industrial tools to properly manipulate EXRs, although it will require a proper chain of nodes to do so. For further explanation along these lines, feel free to check Filmic's issue tracker where some help has been offered regarding the details of such an implementation.

https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender/issues/40

Comment: Other software to explore that will deal with EXR correctly: Fusion, Nuke, and Natron. Those offer proper OCIO support where you can use the filmic-blender transofrms and LUTs on unadulterated EXRs. Also worth exploring: Affinity photo and krita.

Comment: Related link: https://docs.krita.org/Scene_Linear_Painting

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Troy! I have a question about where you said -- It would then be possible to sculpt your own 'S' shaped curve to adjust contrast, or convert the Filmic set to the limited LUT format that Photoshop can understand. --

Comment: Do you mean to do this within photoshop? e.g. Adjust the curves in photoshop, or convert to a LUT format within photoshop? Thanks Again!

Comment: Photoshop has some supremely limited and rather rubbish LUT support. You could either do a hand done curve using curves (yuck) that maps 0.606060 to 0.5 or you could convert and load the files required. I believe Photoshop can load dot cube files. Look to the attached issue for a sample in Google Sheets. Pipeline would be to save as Base Log, then apply the dot cube file as an adjustment layer. Can you report back on this, perhaps even in the Resolve issue thread? (As stated, Photoshop is rather rubbish at all of this.)

Comment: I understand how I import a dot cube file as an adjustment layer now, but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to find the dot cube file for filmic? Is there a specific file you are referring to, or are you just telling me that it would be necessary to apply a LUT to my Base Log file in photoshop?

Comment: Save to a 16 bit TIFF with the base log view. To convert the transform, see the issues thread where I shared the Google Docs dot cube version. It is simply a copying of values, with a change in the header lines. Very easy to do.

Comment: Hey Troy, sorry to bother you about this again, but I've mulled over this for some time and looked at the link you shared, and cannot figure out the next step. I open the 16 bit TIFF in Photoshop. Where do I go from here? I understand I would add a Color Lookup adjustment layer, but where would I get the proper LUT from filmic?

Comment: You would need to try one of the dot cube files out there via the link. Save the spreadsheet as a dot cube, try it on the log encoded image.

Comment: Hey Troy, last question I promise. I've read through the link again. How do I save your spreadsheet as a dot cube? I've looked at other CUBE files, and I don't understand.

Comment: I don't mind questions. At all. Have a look at the issue I posted a reply to at GitHub. It has all of the links required. Simply save the file as a text file, and rename it to dot cube.

Comment: I download your spreadsheet as an excel file. From excel save it as Text (tab delimited), and rename it with .CUBE. But when I use Color Lookup in Photoshop, it doesn't recognize the .CUBE file.

Comment: Just export directly from Google Sheets. I believe Photoshop accepts cube format for layers. Example: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1552879 (Again though, Photoshop is a bit of a ghastly application for this sort of work. It isn't great at photographic material.)