# Rendering with filmic log color space and saving output for use in photoshop

Tags: cycles-render-engine, filmic-blender

I recently learned about the magic of filmic log and love the way it makes my renders look. However, I'm having issue with saving the output from blender. Specifically, for use in photoshop for cropping, sizing and minor image corrections.

My previous workflow was render > save as OpenEXR (rgba / float full) > open in photoshop and save as PSD.

With filmic log, The colors on the EXR file look wildly different in photoshop than they did in the blender rendering output screen. The brighter parts of the images are completely blown out.

Here's an example image, blender on the left, photoshop on the right:
[image: blender left, photoshop right]

I've tried assigning a color profile to the image in photoshop like the filmic log github [suggests](https://github.com/ellelstone/elles_icc_profiles/blob/master/profiles/sRGB-elle-V2-g22.icc). It seems to make no visible difference on screen.

Saving to PNG or TIFF produces darker, low contrast images but does seem to avoid most of the blowout.

Let me know if there's any other info I can provide.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91251/apply-filmic-color-management-to-an-exr-file-post-processing-in-photoshop/91336#91336

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EXR files are always saved without the color management lut applied. They are always linear and is intended for compositing work.

To get a high bit-depth file with the LUT baked in, try saving as 32bit tiff.

Comment: I don't seem to see a 32 bit tiff option. I tried using 16 bit and it's definitely much closer to what I see in the blender render output.