# How do you edit exr files in GIMP without loosing light values?

Tags: texturing, world, hdri

This is the world environment texture in the Gooseberry benchmark:

[image]

If I open the exr in Gimp 2.10, and save it under a new name, then switch to that new file in blender, this is the result:

[image]

No modifications were done, other than opening the file in GIMP and saving it again. Somehow, it gets much darker.

How can I open/edit/save exrs files for environment textures in GIMP, without making unintentional changes to the light values?

Comment: can you attach the exr file for me to try or link to it?

Comment: Hello :). This answer could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102972/. If you wanna get technical, then [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72808/78972)

Comment: Also this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137373/78972

Comment: I don't know how to add an attachment... But the original exr is 60MB, and what GIMP saves is 20MB So it's probably too big to upload.

Comment: Looking at those other questions/ansers, I'm still not sure how to do this. It sounds like the issues is that Blender uses a linear profile that other programs don't (y default). Is GIMP not capable of doing it? Or is there an option to import as linear or export the color management data from Blender? What Linux program is best for working with HDRIs then?